# Multiple server applications, one public IP on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, windows-server-2012-r2, amazon-vpc

I have a single Windows Amazon EC2 instance and one public IP.  The instance is running multiple web server EXEs which all sit on port 80.  I want to have different domain names which I want to point to each server.  On my old dedicated server I achieved this simply by having different public IPs, but with Amazon EC2 I want to keep to just one public IP.

I am not using IIS, Apache, etc. otherwise life would be a lot simpler (I would simply bind hostnames accordingly). The web server executables perform unusual "utility" tasks as part of a range of other websites, but still need to be hosted on port 80.  There is no configuration other than address to bind to and port #.

I have setup several private IPs and bound each server application to those private IPs.  Is it possible to leverage some of the Amazon networking products to direct the traffic to the correct private IP?  e.g. I have tried setting up a private-DNS using Amazon Route53, and internally at least this seems to point to the correct servers - but not (perhaps logically) when I try to access the site externally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In absence of any other solutions I decided to solve this using the blunt hammer approach and use a reverse proxy.  Downside is my servers now only see the user IPs as 127.0.0.1 which was less than ideal, but better than nothing at all.

For my reverse proxy I used Redbird (uses node.js) but Nginx may also be an option.  Both are free / open source.